# Code not returning correct output using if and else statements

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code below is not returning the correct output for some of my tests. I have tried reworking my code to resolve this but have been unable to do so. I am looking for help on how to get my code to return the correct output:

```
def get_translations(string):
"""convert string to list"""
list1 = []
lines = string.splitlines()
order = 1 if string.split(',')[0] == "english" else -1

if 'english,māori' in string:
    for seperate_words in lines:
        list1.append(tuple(seperate_words.split(",")[::order])) 
    
if 'māori,english' in string:
    for seperate_words in lines:
        list1.append(tuple(seperate_words.split(",")[::order]))

else:
    print("Header language not recognized!")
    print("We can't play, hōhā!")
    return -1
    
if len(list1) >= 1:
    print("Kia ora, you have {0} terms to translate today :-)"\
          .format(len(list1) - 1))

number = 0
correct = 0
possible = (len(list1) - 1)

for num in range(len(list1[1:])):
    print("E: {}".format(list1[1+number][0]))
    answer = input("M: ")
    
    if answer == list1[1+number][1]:
        print("Ka pai")
        correct += 1
        number += 1
        
    else:
        print("A: {}".format(list1[1+number][1]))
        number += 1

total = (correct / possible) * 100
return total

def reo_test(string):
    """stuff"""
    return get_translations(string)
```

This is the test that returns the incorrect output:

```
days_string = '''english,māori
Monday,Rāhina
Tuesday,Rātū
Wednesday,Rāapa
Thursday,Rāpare
Friday,Rāmere
Saturday,Rāhoroi
Sunday,Rātapu'''

score = reo_test(days_string)
print("Score {:.2f}".format(score))
```

It should return this (The input is the word following each M letter):

```
Kia ora, you have 7 terms to translate today :-)
E: Monday
M: Rāhina
Ka pai
E: Tuesday
M: Ratū
A: Rātū
E: Wednesday
M: Rātapu
A: Rāapa
E: Thursday
M: Rāari
A: Rāpare
E: Friday
M: Rāmere
Ka pai
E: Saturday
M: Rāhōrōi
A: Rāhoroi
E: Sunday
M: Rātapu
Ka pai
Score 42.86
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here `if 'māori,english' in string:`: the `if` should be an `elif`.
Currently, you correctly build the translations list in the first branch `english,māori`, but then there is a separate `if/else` block, that fails, and so the error is printed.

Cheers, and good luck with your studies!